# SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable UITextField set cursor position when typing emoji

Tags: uikit, swiftui

I'm working with a UITextField wrapped in UIViewRepresentable so I can use it in SwiftUI. I cobbled this together from several SO answers.

```
struct RADTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

    @ObservedObject var dataVM: DataVM
    var placeholder: String
    var isFirstResponder: Bool = false

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<RADTextField>) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField(frame: .zero)
        textField.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFont.TextStyle.body)
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
        textField.returnKeyType = .done
        textField.placeholder = self.placeholder
        textField.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true

        return textField
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> RADTextField.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(dataVM: self.dataVM)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<RADTextField>) {

        uiView.text = dataVM.fieldOne
        if isFirstResponder && !context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder  {
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
            context.coordinator.didBecomeFirstResponder = true
        }
    }

}
```

Coordinator:

```swift
extension RADTextField {
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

        @ObservedObject var dataVM : DataVM
        var didBecomeFirstResponder = false

        init(dataVM: DataVM) {
            self.dataVM = dataVM
        }

        func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
            self.dataVM.fieldOne = textField.text ?? ""
        }

        func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            // Update Cursor
            let positionOriginal = textField.beginningOfDocument

            let cursorLocation = textField.position(from: positionOriginal, offset: (range.location + string.count))

            if let txt = textField.text {
                textField.text = NSString(string: txt).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            }
            // ✳️ I think this is where the issue is ✳️
            if let cursorLocation = cursorLocation {
                textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: cursorLocation, to: cursorLocation)
            }

            return false
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to manually place the cursor somewhere in the text and type an emoji, the next character I type will "split" the emoji. I think some of the emoji characters are actually two characters, but I can't figure out how to deal with that. I marked the code with an ✳️ indicating where I think the issue is.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope. SwiftUI text field was just too messed up and I ended up changing my data entry screens to UIKit. I haven't tried the new SwiftUI features in iOS 14 yet though. Maybe they improved some of this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The need to set the cursor position can be avoided if the UITextField text is not unnecessarily updated with the value from the model each time a character is entered.

This can be achieved by storing the current text received in the textField callback method in a property of the Coordinator. In the updateUIView method this property is used for the comparison with the model value.

This is a simplified example:

```
struct WrappedUITextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
            
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator($text)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.text = text
        return textField
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        if text != context.coordinator.currentText {
            uiView.text = text
        }
    }
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var text: Binding<String>
    var currentText: String
    
    init(_ text: Binding<String>) {
        self.text = text
        currentText = text.wrappedValue
    }
        
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let oldText = textField.text, let textRange = Range(range, in: oldText) else {
            return false
        }

        currentText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: textRange, with: string)
        text.wrappedValue = currentText
        
        return true
    }
}
```

The working two way binding can be tested as follows:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = "example"
    
    var body: some View {
        WrappedUITextField(text: $text)
        WrappedUITextField(text: $text)
    }
}
```